# JTable vs. list of JPanels in JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing

(edited)

I want to display a dynamic list of JPanels that hold textfield that the user can modify. I am having trouble deciding how to design my GUI. Should I display each JPanel in a JTable or a JScrollPane?

The JTable approach, from what I understand, is more memory efficient and faster because I have the getTableCellRenderer method using a cached JPanel to display the table cell's data (edit: I am not storing JPanels in my table just data). The getTableCellEditor method calls the same cached JPanel to capture the user's input. After the input has been captured the data would then be updated to the table. I am not sure how to allow the user to modify multiple components (textfields) of this temporary JPanel before the cell renderer takes over again. The only way I've gotten around this was to create a popup dialog to capture all the information, once the user is done storing the data back to the table. (I think this halts the table cell rendering process, not sure yet.)

The other approach would be just to create and add JPanels to a JScrollPane. However, this would mean I would have to not only store the raw data (integers, strings, etc...) but this would use more memory since I am creating so many JPanel objects. This is obviously the easier approach; However if my list is quite large, then I am sure I will see some hits in performance.

I like the JTable design; however, I hate the fact that when the cell needs to be edited I will need to make a popup to capture the inputs. I don't know, I might just go with the ease of the JScrollPane design.

Does this sound right or am I missing some information about how the getTableCellEditor process works?

Comment: Dacwe, Maybe you misunderstood or you do not fully understand how JTables work. The JPanel is displayed via the getTableCellRenderer method. I use the raw data to update the compontents and return the JPanel object. The JPanel object is then displayed as a cell in the Table.

Comment: That is your design, that is not the way tables work. Table don't work with panels, they work with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like the JTable design; however, I hate the fact that when the cell needs to be edited I will need to make a popup to capture the inputs

Have you read the JTable API and followed the links to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables" for working examples? You don't have to create a popup editor. The cells are edited in place.

For your buttons in the table you will need a custom editor. You can check out Table Button Column for one way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I have looked at the API, it seems that the scope of the object only stays around until the user is done with his/her Action. e.g. When the user clicks on the cell the getTableCellEditor is called and returns the cell object (in this case a JPanel). Once the action is done the object is removed.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to add a new paragraph... not post that yet. Continuing: If I want the user to edit multiple components then each time the user clicked on a sub component of the cell getTableCellEditor would be called.

Comment: Does this mean that for each component in the cell, I wish to edit, would result in a getTableCellEditor call?

Comment: Yes every time you edit a cell an editor is called. What is the problem with this? Again it should NOT return a panel, it should return the data for that cell. If you want to edit all the data in "a panel" or "a row of data in the table", then yes you should be creating a "popup dialog that displays all the data. Then you can enforce that all the data is valid before saving the data back to the panel or the table.

Comment: Yes I am storing the raw data (integer, strings, etc..) as I said in the table data. When the getTableCellEditor is called i create a JPanel for the user with Components (textfields and labels). I understand the JPanel is not store it is created or renderer everytime the user wishes to edit the cell and that the JPanel is just a way to capture and validate inputs before store the "real data" to the table.

Comment: How can I keep the JPanel Editor around long enough for the user modify all the components before the cell is overwritten by the cell renderer again? The only way I've gotten around this was to create a popup dialog, I am not sure if this halts the table cell rendering process or not. ( I will look into this when I get home)

Comment: As I already mentioned a "popup dialog" IS the standard approach, so you are not reinventing the wheel by using this approach. When you close the dialog the TableModel is update and all the values are repainted at the same time.

Comment: OK. Thanks camickr. I figured this was the standard approach since in all the examples in the Java swing documentation they were using some variation of a "popup dialog" (color chooser, file chooser) for a table cell editor. I don't have the reputation to vote for you; but I am grateful for your responses.

Comment: You are still missing something. A JTable comes with default editors for editing single cells so you don't always need to create a popup editor. The editors in the tutorial are for single cells showing how you can create move complex editors. Your case is different because you want to edit a "row" at one time, in which case you create a popup editor for all the value in the row at one time. Don't forget you can "accept" the response that you feel is the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox

Answer (score 0):

`JTable` derives some efficiency from its use of the [*flyweight pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to render and edit cells, as described in [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You can apply the same pattern to your scrolling grid. I've used both approaches, but recently I've come to prefer [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html) in a `JSplitPane`.

Comment: Trashgod, Thanks for the info. I am going to do some research on the flyweight pattern and org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline and get back to you.